# Model attribute is not available as request attribute in JSP page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I am trying to create a sample registration page with **Spring MVC** and JSP pages.

While opening the url on tomcat server, I am getting following error

```
root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'register' available as request attribute
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(
```

I have a JSP **register.jsp**

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Registration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form:form action="/register/process" method="POST" modelAttribute="register">
        <table style="text-align: center;">

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="fname">First Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="fname" name="fname"
                        id="fname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="lname">Last Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="lname" name="lname" id="lname" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                <input type="submit" value="CREATE AN ACCOUNT"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
   </body>
  </html>
```

I have a controller class **UserController.java**

```
package vnfhub.supplier.controller;

@Controller
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getRegisterForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("register", new Register());
        return "register";
    }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/register/process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String processRegistration(@ModelAttribute("register") Register register, BindingResult result) {
       return "success";
   }
}
```

and a **success.jsp page**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Success Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<font color="green"><h1>Hello</h1></font>

<h1>You have successfully registered</h1>
<font color="green"><h1>Welcome to Spring world !</h1></font>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried many solution on stackoverflow.... but none of them worked.

Comment: In which handler method you are getting this exception ? In **GET** or **POST** ?

Comment: GET.....http://localhost:8075/sample/register

Comment: I tried to regenerate your exception with your code. But this seems okay to me. Could you try to clean build and rerun the project ?

Comment: Why you are adding  `model.addAttribute("register", new Register());` attributes will be automatically bind to the model atribute in `register/process`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your code okay so far as you given here. I mimic the situation with your code but unfortuantely found **No Exception**.

[image]

Things that you might have doing wrong is you are running some old build code in your tomcat. try to **clean build** and **re-deploy** in your container.

**NB:** one friendly suggestion. **You are doing one thing wrong** that is having action of your form to `/register/process` that will send the request to the container root (e.g. `localhost:8080/register/process`). And you will get `404` for that. You are not probably want that. `register/process` should be your URL and this will POST the request relative to your application-context. If your application context is something `localhost:8080/test`, this will send the request to `localhost:8080/test/register/process`

Comment: Thanks.....Cleaning the projects and the URL issue is resolved....
Help is highly appreciated...:)